# What is the difference between Zend & CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, zend-framework

I would like to know what is the different between CodeIgniter and Zend MVC Framework in regarding to coding style?

e.g. Retrieving/Inserting values in the database etc.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. 
Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept are similar but the coding style is different:

Zend Framework uses both table gateway pattern and row gateway pattern but CodeIgniter only uses the later.

If you are asking about the conventions used in naming variables and methods then Zend is different from CodeIgniter. Therefore the coding style are not the same!

Hope it helps!